# How to install PHP-intl on Centos PHP 7.2

Tags: php7

My PHP 7.2 application is giving the error `Message: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found`

We are running:

- PHP 7.2.34
- CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

I tried to install PHP-intl and it seemed to work as now if I try again I get this:

```
# yum install php72-php-intl
# Package php72-php-intl-7.2.34-4.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
# Nothing to do
```

I have reloaded Apache but the extension is not loaded:

- `php -m` does not list the module.
- **/usr/lib64/php/modules** does not contain `intl.so`

By running `rpm -ql php72-php-intl` I can see these files are installed:

```
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/20-intl.ini
/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/intl.so
```

But the extension_dir is set to **/usr/lib64/php/modules**

Why is it installed to this other location? And how can I either get it to install to the correct modules directory or otherwise what is the correct way to tell PHP to load the .so file from  **/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-intl
```

It installed it to **/usr/lib64/php/modules**. Also additionally I did not have to add it manually to **/etc/php.ini** (and doing so caused an error that it is already loaded)

I don't know why `--enablerepo=remi` is required, or what it means – because `yum install php72-php-intl` evidently installs it (albeit to the wrong place and not enabled).

My understanding was that if the repo was not enabled it would not be found or installed at all.

Comment: For a proper installation, follow the wizard instructions: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Comment: Also read the FAQ about difference between php-intl and php72-intl: https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl

Comment: Thank you @RemiCollet – this helps a lot. So I previously installed php72-php-intl which was installed beside the default system.